# deserialize nested json from API

Tags: jquery, json, api

For some reason I can not get to the `price` variable to extract from this JSON:

```
{
    "list": {
        "meta": {
            "type": "resource-list",
            "start": 0,
            "count": 1
        },
        "resources": [{
            "resource": {
                "classname": "Quote",
                "fields": {
                    "change": "-0.979900",
                    "chg_percent": "-1.955109",
                    "day_high": "49.290001",
                    "day_low": "48.200001",
                    "issuer_name": "Delta Air Lines, Inc.",
                    "issuer_name_lang": "Delta Air Lines, Inc.",
                    "name": "Delta Air Lines, Inc. Common St",
                    "price": "49.140099",
                    "symbol": "DAL",
                    "ts": "1458663972",
                    "type": "equity",
                    "utctime": "2016-03-22T16:26:12+0000",
                    "volume": "7921714",
                    "year_high": "52.770000",
                    "year_low": "34.610000"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I am using: `this.list.resources.resource.fields.price` but it is not working

Comment: Yes Rory is right .  list.resources[0].resource.fields.price should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources` is an array, so you need to access it by index:

```
this.list.resources[0].resource.fields.price;
```

This is obviously assuming there is only 1 entry in the array. If there are multiple you would need to loop through them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.list.resources.length; i++) {
    var price = this.list.resources[i].resource.fields.price;
    // do something with the price here...
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/sLkxfk64/)

Also note that as this value is a price you may want to consider using `toFixed(2)` on it to force it to 2 decimal places, but be aware that this coerces the type to a string so make sure you do any calculations on it beforehand.

Comment: I added the array bracket but I might have typed it wrong.